# Mixed model with constraints on random coefficents

Tags: mixed-model

I am interested in estimating this linear/nonlinear mixed model:

y[i,t] = f( a[i] + b1[i] * x1[i,t] + b1[i] * r * x2[i,t] )

, where b1 >=0 for all i's and 0 <= r <= 1.  f() is the link function, which can be the identity link.

Therefore, this model has a random intercept, a[i], and a random slope, b1[i].

Which package can I do this and how I can set it up?  Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify the sense in which this is a mixed model: which terms are random?  Is there an implicit random error you have not written?

Comment: I edited the question.  Thanks for the feedback.